# What is the term for how close a phonetic expression is to its meaning?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, terminology

In some cases, the cognates of onomatopoetic sounds are highly similar even across unrelated languages. In these cases, the sounds of words seem to be an attempt to echo naturally occurring sounds. Other words follow etymology stemming patterns. Still others have no known relationship to what they attempt to express, or to existing expressions; I'm in fact not aware of any, but pretty sure they exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Cognates are words in different languages that have a common origin ie are related, so saying 'cognates of onomatopoeic sounds are highly similar even across unrelated languages' doesn't make sense. And what does '...onomatopoeic sounds' mean? It's words that are onomatopoeic. Also, if they're onomatopoeic words they should sound similar across different (even unrelated) languages, as that's what onomatopoeia means.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you mean by 'closeness' of a 'phonetic expression' to its 'meaning'? Perhaps what you're looking for is 'phonaestheme' the conventionalised pairing of form and meaning. While the relationship between sounds and meanings is (onomatopeia apart) mostly arbitrary, within any given language certain sounds can be conventionalised as having a particular meaning/lassociation. An example in English is the /gl/-initial words, many of which have a meaning related to light, so /gl/- is a phonaestheme. If you can clarify a bit, I might be able to expand on this as an answer.

Comment: +2 @Gaston Ümlaut: Onomatopoeic words should sound similar across different languages, but that's not always the case. Onomatopoeic words are the words for the sound. An onomatopoeic sound is the sound for the cognates.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: And yes, phonestheme appears to cover the etymology stemming patterns. Onomatopoetic alignment would be I'm guessing a sort based on the phonetic expression (in this case an onomatopeia) to the natural sound taking into account what sounds human are able to expression. Still unclear what I'm after? Just to be clear, I have zero background in linguistics and it's terminology, my interest is in the application of linguistic concepts. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: pretty sure -what- exists?

Comment: An onoomatopoeic word is a word that imitates or suggests the source that it represents. But I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about 'an onomatopoeic sound' are you using that to refer to the sound which is being imitated in the word? And you're calling the set of onomatopoeic words across different languages,  that have the same referent, the 'cognates'? 'Cognate' refers to words in diff langs, that descend from a common ancestor.

Comment: @blunders: the distinction you're trying to draw between onom. words and onom. sounds is not clear at all. Can you explain?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. But there's no terminology I've heard of for describing the degree of similarity of a word to its referent. Onomatopoeia refers to words that imitate the source of the sound, but I don't know of any discussion of degrees of accuracy of the imitation. Other words have no natural connection between form and meaning; phonaesthemes are _conventionalised_ pairings of form and meaning, ie they are arbitrary, and there is no similarity between the sound and the meaning.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: Yes, I'm using 'an onomatopoeic sound' as the sound referenced. My understanding is that an onomatopeia is a pairing of a natural sound and a phonetic expression. In some cases so commonly used, it's called a word, which only really makes sense if the word becomes the sound; for example, laughter in some cases mimics onomatopoeic word for laughter; meaning I've never heard a baby go "ha ha ha...". That's my take on it, very possible I'm might be misunderstanding something. And yes, we're both using 'cognate' to refer words that descend from a common ancestor from diff langs.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: My take is that completely arbitrary words, those whose expression makes no attempt to align to an existing expression of related meaning... are farther from onomatopoeic words, than phonaesthemic words, when it comes to how close the words are to their meaning.

Comment: @Mitch: ('onom' = Onomatopoeia, correct?) -- please see my reply to Gaston Ümlaut, if it's still not clear, please attempt to point of the conflicts in meaning, or the absence of meaning within quoted text.

Comment: @Mitch: Edited the body of the question to make it more clear to address your comment, "pretty sure -what- exists?"... those edits being, "Still others have no known relationship to what they attempt to express, or to existing expressions; I'm in fact not aware of any, but pretty sure they exist." -- which is to say, I'm pretty sure words which is truly arbitrary exist. Words that display phonaestheme are not arbitrary phonetic expressions.

Comment: @blunders You suggest that phonaesthemes are closer to onomatopoeia but this is not right. Phonaesthemes don't imitate the sound of their meaning, they are simply conventionalised associations within a language. But speakers of a language often become so used to these arbitrary associations that they think of them as natural. [Here's](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/mnemonic_initials.htm) a list of phonaestheme initials--to many English speakers, a nonsense word using one of these will be interpreted as having a meaning that matches the phonaestheme.

Comment: @blunders: I'm pretty sure too that some words exist that are truly arbitrary. namely the vast majority of them. Evidence? Open your ears and a dictionary of any language at random. Pick a word. Does the sound sequence have any relation whatsoever to the thing labeled? 'Pferd', 'cheval', 'ma3', 'hasan', 'horse', 'kutirai', etc. etc. all __totally__ arbitrary. __Onomatopoeia is rare__.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: My logic is phonaesthemes imitate the sound of a arbitrary phonetic expression which references a meaning. Phonaesthemes reference a sound, just not the sound of the meaning, which in my opinion is closer than being arbitrary in assigning phonetic expressions to sounds. All my opinion, and I understand your position is the position we both believe linguistic professional would state too. Just to be clear, I've never thought of phonaestheme as natural, except that they reference an existing expression. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Mitch: Onomatopoeia is rare. Some words reference the reference, which is less arbitrary than something being totally arbitrary; for example, blunders while a word, was a totally arbitrary choice of words to be my username. When I created the account, it was the word in the reCAPTCHA SE gave me.

Comment: @blunders: none of those 'phonaesthenes' are onom. (yes, I'm abbreviating the word in question). How does phonaesthene 'reference a sound' any more than any other arbitrary phonological sequence. I don't understand your 'reference the reference' idea; your examples has nothing to do with sounds.

Comment: @blunders I think phonaesthemes are better thought of as a kind of morphological element which is reused, rather than as a set of discrete elements which imitate some 'original' (?) ones. Otherwise, following your logic, we'd conclude that the 'pre' in 'prenuptial' is a phonaestheme because it's imitating the sound of the 'pre' in 'preliminary' (or whatever word you deem the 'original' use of 'pre'). We'd have phoneasthemes everywhere!

Comment: @blunders, your question would be improved by some actual examples of onomatopoeic words that are very similar in unrelated languages, and I really don't know what you mean by 'etymology stemming patterns', but some examples of that would be good too. People will understand your query better if they have some examples of the phenomena you are trying to describe.

Comment: +1 @Floating Tone: In response to your request for examples of onomatopoeic words that are very similar in unrelated languages, here are some examples of [cross-linguistic onomatopoeias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias). The examples of 'etymology stemming patterns' I was thinking of were Latin/Greek word roots, though the [list of phonaestheme initials](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/mnemonic_initials.htm) Gaston Ümlaut linked to in his comment apply as well. Basically, it's a bad question, though it was of use to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no terminology for the level of closeness a 'phonetic expression' takes to its 'meaning', quite simply because this is not something that is researched or discussed in linguistic circles, as there is no real reason to engage in this sort of enquiry.
Here are some reasons why:

1) As addressed in the comments, and as widely believed throughout linguistics, **most words are arbitrary with regards to their meaning**, with no real connection between the types and combinations of sounds in the word to the referent.

2) When onomatopoeia does occur (and it is rare, in that most languages have a tiny number of onomatopoeic words compared to arbitrary words), it is essentially formalised mimicry. As has been pointed out, you can't get very far comparing human vocalisations to non-human sounds, whether they are sounds of animal calls, falling rocks, rushing water, or whatever. All of these real-world sounds will be produced by very different means, and humans can, at best, come up with an approximation of them that works with the constraints of the human vocal tract. More importantly, **an onomatopoeic word can't just try to imitate a referent sound as precisely as possible - it also has to abide by the phoneme inventory, phonotactics and phonological processes specific to the language, at least to a certain extent**. This is the main reason why onomatopoeic sounds vary cross-linguistically, plus the fact that different speakers may have different perceptions of the same referent sound, and may therefore be mimicking different aspects of it.

Furthermore, an onomatopoeic word is, by virtue of being formalised, a word like any other, and **subject to the same processes of language change**, in particular sound change. This will also account for a lot of variation in onomatopoeic words for the same referent, and something which may have originally been a close approximation of a referent sound is likely to become further and further removed from it.

3) There is an active area of research into **sound symbolism**, but the findings are in general tenuous, and are certainly not based on direct correspondences between a word and a particular sound or thing it references. Rather, **research on sound symbolism investigates the more subtle connections between certain types of sounds and certain types of very broad, non-concrete meanings**. E.g. sonorants as opposed to obstruents, or voiced sounds as opposed to voiceless sounds, or back vowels as opposed to high front vowels, and the connotations they seem to have of qualities such as 'spikiness' or 'roundness', or 'sweetness' or 'sourness', or 'tiny-ness' or 'big-ness', and so on. [There is an accessible overview of such research in this New Scientist article.](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21128211.600-kiki-or-bouba-in-search-of-languages-missing-link.html?full=true) Phonestheme research falls under this category, too.

Sound symbolism research has found some very interesting patterns based on human interpretations of nonsense words (and this has produced a wealth of knowledge for advertisers coming up with new brand names and slogans), but this is not so straightforward as an easily observable connection between the sound of the word and the referent, and of course there is still no terminology to describe the degree of similarity between the two, because **the referent doesn't generally *have* a sound in many examples of sound symbolism**. (What is the sound of 'sour'?)

Comment: +1 @Floating Tone: Selecting your post as the answer, since it shows clear effort, and does a good job of covering all the issues addressed via comments and other answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The terminology for how much a word sounds like its meaning is pretty simple:

- onomatopoeia - a word or short sequence of phonemes that is imitative of a non-linguistic sound. for example the sound of a bee is called 'buzzing' in English, the voiced alveolar fricative evocative of the drone of the bee. In comparison to all the sounds humans make, these sequences are very rare.

That's it. In fact the vast majority of linguistically produced sequences are so arbitrary and so distant from imitation, that there is no specialword for the larger set of non-onomatopoeic words. And there is no real 'in-between' stage of 'somewhat sounding like the thing it stands for, but not quite', because onomatopoeia includes that too. For example, in a bee buzzing, have you ever heard a voiced bilabial stop? That is 'in between' but is still considered onomatopoeia.

Comment: While I've stated this above, I'll restate if here. My reading of your answer is that there is no terminology for the level of closeness a phonetic expression takes to it's meaning beyond onomatopoeia, which in itself only notes the pairs of a word and sound, not how closely they align. Which is fine, though I'm commenting in an attempt to just make sure it's clear what I'm asking is the same as your understanding of it.

Comment: @blunders: es, your reading sounds like what I think I'm saying.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no specific term for how well an onomatopoeic word approximates the sound it refers to, because there is no way to measure how alike two sounds are. Remember that nearly every utterance made by the human vocal apparatus is a combination of several articulators sounding in unison (or phased relative to each other), making their output even more difficult to compare to any given sound in nature.

Comment: To be fair, you could probably do a rough measure of similarity between two speech sounds (phones), espec two vowels or two consonants. But I agree, measuring similarity between a speech sound and a non-speech sound doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Yeah, comparing two speech sounds is a well-researched problem, and roughly consists of reducing each signal into a set of parameters, then comparing those. But I agree, the space of *all* possible sounds, speech and non-speech, is far too large to be amenable to this kind of analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood what you're looking for.  But if I understand your question right, there *is* a term for what you're talking about: *iconicity*. In cognitive linguistics, expressions that are similar in form and meaning are said to be "more iconic" than expressions that don't show that sort of similarity.

So for instance, an onomatopoetic animal name like *cuckoo* is said to be "more iconic" than a non-onomatopoetic one like *eagle*.  If you say something is *lo-o-o-o-o-ong*, with a lengthened vowel, that's "more iconic" than saying *very long*.  If you say *he did it over and over and over*, repeating the word to indicate a repeated event, that's "more iconic" than saying *he did it many times*.  Saying *he went home and fell asleep*, with the events described in the same order in which they occurred, is "more iconic" than saying *he fell asleep after going home.*

Still, I agree with all the caveats that other folks have given you.  It is impossible to quantify exactly how iconic an expression is — there's no, like, "iconicity quotient" you can calculate.  And often it's not even clear which of two expressions should count as more iconic than the other. Is *cuckoo* more or less iconic than *whipporwill*?  Or for that matter, is *eagle* more or less iconic than *pigeon*?  There's really no way to answer.

So as a concept it's not always very useful, and it's certainly not very precise.  Still, the concept is *there* if you want to use it.